# Decompile a simple recursive function and get a loop with unnecessary code

Tags: f#

I would like to see if the following 2 simple recursive function would perform as well as C# versions, so I decompiled them into C# using ILSPY.

```
    let rec findPivot i =
        if i = 0 then -1
        else
            if myArray.[i] > myArray.[i-1] then i - 1
            else findPivot (i - 1)

    let rec findTarget value i =
        if (myArray.[i] > value) then i
        else findTarget value (i - 1)
```

Getting:

```
internal static int findPivot@11(int[] myArray, int i)
{
    while (i != 0)
    {
        if (myArray[i] > myArray[i - 1])
        {
            return i - 1;
        }
        int[] arg_22_0 = myArray; // useless
        i--;
        myArray = arg_22_0; // useless
    }
    return -1;
}

internal static int findTarget@17(int[] myArray, int value, int i)
{
    while (myArray[i] <= value)
    {
        int[] arg_16_0 = myArray; // useless
        int arg_14_0 = value; // useless
        i--;
        value = arg_14_0; // useless
        myArray = arg_16_0; // useless
    }
    return i;
}
```

I am surprised that F# compiled would generate such messy code. Although it might not affect performance (JIT may optimize further). I am still a bit concern about the performance when the code is more complicated and critical in the system.

Any comments on why the compiler emits such code?

Comment: Did you actually look at the IL rather than the decompiled code - the F# compiler actually generates quite good il so maybe the decompiler converting back to C# is producing odd code.

Comment: In addition to John Palmer's observation, keep in mind that the IL isn't what's actually run anyway - the JIT compiler may optimize out unneeded operations when converting to machine code.  I'd profile the code to see if you have an actual performance problem, rather than preemptively worrying about it.

Comment: +1 to kvb's point. Check this: https://gist.github.com/v2m/5530153 - JIT optimizes out manipulations with stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked into it and it seems that the IL is being misinterpreted as a declaration of a new local. Keep in mind that the F# compiler generates IL that won't always match the C# compiler. It seems that F# compiler will reassign the arguments regardless if they are mutated within the loop. Take notice that we have no locals declared so everything is being pushed onto the stack.

```
.method public static 
    int32 findTarget (
        int32 'value',
        int32 i
    ) cil managed 
{
    .custom instance void [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilationArgumentCountsAttribute::.ctor(int32[]) = (
        01 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00
    )
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2084
    // Code size 27 (0x1b)
    .maxstack 8

    // loop start
        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: call int32[] Program::get_myArray()
        IL_0006: ldarg.1
        IL_0007: ldelem.any [mscorlib]System.Int32
        IL_000c: ldarg.0
        IL_000d: ble.s IL_0011

        IL_000f: ldarg.1
        IL_0010: ret

        IL_0011: ldarg.0
        IL_0012: ldarg.1
        IL_0013: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0014: sub
        IL_0015: starg.s i
        IL_0017: starg.s 'value'
        IL_0019: br.s IL_0000
    // end loop
} // end of method Program::findTarget
```